# Swift. Есть Вью, есть отдельный файл с Моделью. Не могу подключить в storyboard IBOutlet (лежит в Модели) к объекту Лейбл висящий во viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, connect

Я новичок. Первый раз тут задаю вопрос. Ответ очень искал и тут и в гугл, но тупо не нашел, поэтому если он есть уже тут, буду очень благодарен за ссылку!!!

Swift. Есть Вью (с подключенным классом к ней MainViewController), есть отдельный файл с Моделью (CourseCell.swift). IBOutlet вручную прописал в Модели. И надо ж подключить их к объектами. Не могу подключить IBOutlet (которые лежат в Модели, повторюсь) к объектам UILabel и UIImageView висящими в interface builder в MainViewController !!

Кажется банальным вопрос, но тупо не могу драг эн дропом подключить, полоска для создания не появляется при перетаскивании, подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно делать в таком случае ??

class CourseCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberOfLessons: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberOfQuestions: UILabel!
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указать кастомный класс ячейки, в вашем случае CourseCell:

[image: CourseCell]

[image: MainViewController]

Comment: Понимаю, но мне ведь надо чтобы там был MainViewController. А если я ставлю CourseCell, конекчу атлеты, а потом меняю обратно на нужный MainViewController, то привязка сбивается (пустые точки снова становятся)

Comment: MainViewController вы указываете в UIViewController, а CourseCell в UITableViewCell, это разные сущности (классы). Добавил картинку в ответ.

Comment: Пфффффф!!! Спасибо Огромное, реально еще бы долго искал такую простую вещь! Спасибо большое за быструю помощь Олег!

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад что помог)